# Is there any way to remove/replace carriage returns from an opened file being read by csv.DictReader?

Tags: python, csv, carriage-return

I have some large files with delimited fields that sometimes contain carriage returns ('`\r`'). I would like to use the `DictReader` (or even `reader`) from the `csv` library, but apparently the `lineterminator` argument doesn't do anything and both carriage returns and newlines are hardcoded into the system ([source](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator)).

For the sake of preserving the data, I would like to at least be able to replace the carriage returns (even if with something like `'\\r'`) so that the files can be stored into a database and have the original text retrieved (something like `'\\r'` could easily be converted into a newline if it needed to be displayed to a user).

Some of the files are extremely large, and I do not want to read the entire file into memory.

The encoding for the files is either 'UTF-8' or 'latin-1'

Comment: Please add an small example of what your CSV file would look like.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a script to simply remove any blank lines from the files as follows:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        if row:
            csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Or if you know that valid rows must have say `5` columns you could use:

```
if len(row) == 5:
```

This assumes you are using Python 2.x. For Python 3.x you would need:

```
with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
```

For example, if `input.csv` was:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6

7,8,9

10,11,12



13,14,15
```

The `output.csv` file would become:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
13,14,15
```